# This line works fine alone but does not work in for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to form a dictionary of sets but my code seem to work outside the for loop but fails inside it.

Thanks for any help

```
for n in xrange(tc):
    truckgoals[n]= set()

#this works fine    
truckgoals[0].add(packages[0]["target"])

for sol in feas:
    print "for solutions" + str(sol)
    for c in xrange(pcount):
        print int(sol[c])
        # this fails
        truckgoals[int(sol[c])].add(packages[c]["target"])
    for tur in xrange(tc):
        print "goals of truck " +str(tur) + " is " + str(truckgoals[tur]) 
    print "next"
    truckgoals = [0] * tc
    pass
```

ERROR:

```
...
for solutions(0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mbp/workspace/Case Study/main.py", line 103, in <module>
    truckgoals[int(sol[c])].add(packages[c]["target"])
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You replaced `truckgoals` with a list *in the loop*:

```
truckgoals = [0] * tc
```

This creates a list of length `tc` with integers.

Since you are using `xrange()` to produce the keys for your dictionary, it looks to me as if a list of sets instead of a dictionary would be a better option, in any case.

Comment: @Kartopukus: Why would you clear the whole dictionary? Did you want to clear the *sets* instead? At the very least, reset it to a dictionary with the same keys and empty sets. Better still, use a `defaultdict(set)` instance and values will be created as needed.